# Automapper convert ExpandoObject to Dictionary of custom objects

Tags: c#, automapper, expandoobject

I have an expandoObject such as

```
var attributeToMapFrom = new ExpandoObject();
attributeToMapFrom.Add("1", "Attribute1");
attributeToMapFrom.Add("2", "Attribute2");
```

I also have a class in my application called 'CustomAttribute'

```
public class CustomAttribute
{
    public int Id;
    public string AttributeValue;
}
```

And another place that uses a dictionary of them:

```
var dict = new dictionary<int, CustomAttribute>();
```

I'd like to use Automapper to map the values in the expandoObject into a Dictionary, so that I end up with a dictionary containing:

```
Key  |  Value
1    |  CustomAttribute{Id = 1, AttributeValue = "Attribute1"}
2    |  CustomAttribute{Id = 2, AttributeValue = "Attribute2"}
```

I'd like to map it thus:

```
var attributeToMapFrom = new ExpandoObject();

attributeToMapFrom.Add("1", "Attribute1");
attributeToMapFrom.Add("2", "Attribute2");

var mappedAttributes = new Dictionary<int, CustomAttribute>();
this.Mapper.Map(attributeToMapFrom, mappedAttributes);
```

I'm using the following in the mapper config:

```
CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, object>,CustomAttribute>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AttributeId, src => src.MapFrom(t => Convert.ToInt32(t.Key)));


       CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, object>, KeyValuePair<int, CustomAttribute>>()
  .ConstructUsing( x => new KeyValuePair<int, CustomAttribute>( Convert.ToInt32(x.Key), x.MapTo<CustomAttribute>() ) );
```

I thought the second createmap would create the keyValuePairs of the  dictinary, using the first to make the values. It doesn't work (or compile, actually...)

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Remove your map and try one from string to CustomAttribute. Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: You were absolutely right - it needed to know how to convert the 'object' part of my expandoObject (which was a string in my example) into the CustomAttribute - I wasn't expecting it to need that given it could already do this: CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, object>,CustomAttribute>(). Also didn't know about the exection plan - Thanks very much!